# Java : Reading larger excel files for processing

Tags: java, excel, jvm, heap-memory, jxls

We have to process large excel files around the size 5 MB - 10 MB. We used JXLS to read excel and populate the beans.

We use WebSphere 6.1 for the deployment with heap size 512 MB and max heap size of 1024 MB. OutOfMemoryError is seen while reading the excel it self.

Any suggestions to overcome this?

like

Is there a way to read single sheet in excel without reading complete file and process it ?

Comment: how many xls files do you need to process ?
You should maybe try to monitor your JVM with some memory profiler tool like jvisualvm to investigate where the memory is going.

Comment: I have to process only one XLS file which contains 15 -20 sheets of data. I am reading the complete XLS at once using mapping file and adding end lines to each tab.

Answer (score 0):

A 5-10MB Excel file doesn't seem to be a large file to me ...

Are you sure the OutOfMemoryError comes from the reading-excel-file process ?

You can try some alternate lib like [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) or [POI](http://poi.apache.org/).
I've used both, I prefer POI.